# Localization of the Application Title for Windows Phone 7 app - windows marketplace hickup

Tags: windows-phone-7, localization, marketplace

Basically, I followed that Microsoft provided How-to
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff967550(v=VS.92).aspx 
to localize my applications title.
Worked like a charm, but now I wanted to upload my app to the windows marketplace for publishing and there my application title is shown everywhere as

```
@AppResLib.dll, -100
```

Should I just ignore it?
Will it magically work "later"?
Did I do something wrong or is it just impossible to have localized app titles in the marketplace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, with a hint from the WP7 developer forum I found out that in the WMAppManifest.xml /  the entry

```
Title="@AppResLib.dll, -100"
```

will never work because the correct one has to be

```
Title="@AppResLib.dll,-100"
```

.
Ouch!
Solved.